# SQL Alchemy: Keeping order of items with N:M relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have Folders that contain Items.
Each Item can only be assigned to one Folder.
I want to remember the order of each item in that folder.

Originally, the system was created like this:

```
class Folder(Base):
   __tablename__ = "folder"
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

   items = relationship(
      "Item",
      back_populates="folder",
      cascade="all, delete-orphan",
   )

   item_ordering = Column(ARRAY(String), default=[])

class Item(Base):
   __tablename_ = "item"
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   folder_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("folder.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
   folder = relationship("Folder", back_populates="signal_boards")
```

The ordering was stored as a list. However, we often had a case where the list of IDs diverted from the real list of items in the folder.
To make this more robust, I tried the following approach (I followed the [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#combining-association-object-with-many-to-many-access-patterns) for the Association Pattern and [SQLAlchemy another doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/cascades.html#using-foreign-key-on-delete-with-many-to-many-relationships) for the deletion):

```
class Folder(Base):
    __tablename__ = "folder"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    items = relationship(
        "Item",
        secondary="folder_item_association",
        back_populates="folder",
        order_by="desc(folder_item_association.c.order)",
        single_parent=True,  # N:M -> 1:M
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
    )
    item_associations = relationship(
        "FolderItemAssociation",
        back_populates="folder",
        order_by="desc(FolderItemAssociation.order)",
        single_parent=True,  # N:M -> 1:M
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
    )


class FolderItemAssociation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "folder_item_association"

    project_id = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey("folder.id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        primary_key=True,
    )
    item_id = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey("item.id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        primary_key=True,
        unique=True,  # one workspace can be associated with only one project
    )
    order = Column(
        BigInteger,
        autoincrement=True,
    )

    folder = relationship(
        "Folder",
        back_populates="item_associations",
    )
    item = relationship(
        "Item",
        back_populates="folder_association",
    )

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "item"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    folder = relationship( 
        "Folder",
        secondary="folder_item_association",
        back_populates="items",
        passive_deletes=True,
        uselist=False,
    )
    folder_association = relationship(
        "FolderItemAssociation",
        back_populates="item",
        passive_deletes=True,
        uselist=False,
    )
```

This works fine (unless I made some errors by making it generic).
The problem that I have is that deletes are not cascaded. If I delete a Folder, it and the association entry are deleted, but the Item remains orphaned and is not deleted.
I tried many things but I can't make it work that the cascading works.

I would appreciate help. I created a test to see if it works:

```
def test_item_objects_should_be_deleted():

    with session_scope() as session:
        folder = Folder(
            id="test_fid",
            items=[
                Item(
                    id="test_iid",
                )
            ]
        )
        session.add(folder)
        session.commit()

        counts = (
            session.query(Folder).count(),
            session.query(FolderItemAssociation).count(),
            session.query(Item).count(),
        )  # -> (1, 1, 1)

        session.query(Folder).delete()
        session.commit()

        counts = (
            session.query(Folder).count(),
            session.query(FolderItemAssociation).count(),
            session.query(Item).count(),
        )  # -> (0, 0, 1)


        assert counts == (0,) * len(counts), f"{counts} is not just zeros."
```

Comment: I'm suprised this doesn't throw a warning without viewonly=True on the direct 1 to many relationship.  It should work somehow with the association but why not just put the ordering column directly on the item if each item is only in 1 folder?

Comment: What version of sqlalchemy are you using?

Comment: I am using SQLAlachemy 1.4 (unfortunately, we can't upgrade to 2 yet)

Regarding putting the order into the item. I thought about it, but I'm not happy with that design choice. The order is generally not a property of the Item, it is a property of the link between the folder and the item. So, I tried to model it that way. I believe this is a cleaner design, but it is a matter of personal preference, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short story is that the `FolderItemAssociation.item` relationship needs `single_parent=True` and `cascade="all, delete-orphan"` set.  Only one server side cascade will work between FolderItemAssociation and Item and in this setup the item's removal triggers the association's removal.  So SQLAlchemy has to enforce the item removal when an association is removed (ie. cascade in the other direction).

As far as I know you can't have both the association and the secondary in use at the same time unless you set the secondary relationship (ie. `Folder.items` ) as `viewonly=True`.  In this case I took them out because it is confusing to work with both when there is a problem but you could try adding it back with `viewonly=True`.

I am using postgresql and the `order` column doesn't autopopulate for me.  I'm not sure which db you have or that is working for you but at least this is a starting point.

```py
import sys
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
    BigInteger,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
    ForeignKey,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session, aliased, relationship, joinedload


Base = declarative_base()


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=False)

'''
class Folder(Base):
    __tablename__ = "folder"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    items = relationship(
        "Item",
        back_populates="folder",
        order_by="desc(Item.order)",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
    )


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "item"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    folder_id = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey("folder.id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        nullable=False
    )

    order = Column(
        BigInteger,
        autoincrement=True,
        nullable=False
    )

    folder = relationship(
        "Folder",
        back_populates="items",
    )
'''

class Folder(Base):
    __tablename__ = "folder"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    item_associations = relationship(
        "FolderItemAssociation",
        back_populates="folder",
        order_by="desc(FolderItemAssociation.order)",
        single_parent=True,  # N:M -> 1:M
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Folder(id={self.id}, item_associations={', '.join(repr(assoc) for assoc in self.item_associations)})"


class FolderItemAssociation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "folder_item_association"

    project_id = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey("folder.id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        primary_key=True,
    )
    item_id = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey("item.id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        primary_key=True,
        unique=True,  # one workspace can be associated with only one project
    )
    order = Column(
        BigInteger,
        # --- This does not work for me. ---
        autoincrement=True,
    )

    folder = relationship(
        "Folder",
        back_populates="item_associations",
    )
    item = relationship(
        "Item",
        back_populates="folder_association",
        # --- ADDED ---
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        single_parent=True
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Assoc(id={(self.project_id, self.item_id)}, order={self.order}, item={repr(self.item)})"

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "item"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    folder_association = relationship(
        "FolderItemAssociation",
        back_populates="item",
        passive_deletes=True,
        uselist=False,
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item(id={self.id})"

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


def reset(session):
    session.query(Folder).delete()
    session.query(FolderItemAssociation).delete()
    session.query(Item).delete()
    session.commit()

    # After a reset everything should be zero.
    assert_counts(session, (0, 0, 0))


def assert_counts(session, expected_counts):
    counts = get_counts(session)
    assert counts == expected_counts, f'Expected {expected_counts} but got {counts}'


def get_counts(session):
    return (
        session.query(Folder).count(),
        session.query(FolderItemAssociation).count(),
        session.query(Item).count(),
    )


def create_sample_folders(session):
    folder1 = Folder(
        item_associations=[
            FolderItemAssociation(item=Item()), FolderItemAssociation(item=Item())
        ]
    )
    session.add(folder1)
    folder2 = Folder(
        item_associations=[
            FolderItemAssociation(item=Item()), FolderItemAssociation(item=Item())
        ]
    )
    session.add(folder2)
    session.commit()

    print(repr(folder1))
    print(repr(folder2))


def test1():
    """ All items in folder should be deleted when a folder is deleted. """
    with Session(engine) as session:
        create_sample_folders(session)
        assert_counts(session, (2, 4, 4))

        session.delete(session.query(Folder).first())
        session.commit()

        assert_counts(session, (1, 2, 2))

        reset(session)

test1()


def test2():
    """ When an item is deleted, the folder should not be deleted. """

    with Session(engine) as session:
        create_sample_folders(session)

        assert_counts(session, (2, 4, 4))

        session.delete(session.query(Item).first())
        session.commit()

        assert_counts(session, (2, 3, 3))

        reset(session)

test2()


def test3():
    """ When an associations are deleted, their items are deleted, the folder should not be deleted. """

    with Session(engine) as session:
        create_sample_folders(session)

        assert_counts(session, (2, 4, 4))

        session.delete(session.query(FolderItemAssociation).first())
        session.commit()

        assert_counts(session, (2, 3, 3))

        reset(session)

test3()
```

Comment: This example is using sqlalchemy 2.0 but I think it should be pretty similar in 1.4.

Comment: I re-implemented the relationships exactly like you did, but it still doesn't work.
It might be a bug in 1.4. 
Also, the autoincrement works fine on my end, and I use PostgreSQL. How odd. :/

Comment: Did you remove the other relations?  I tried it with `sqlalchemy-1.4.50` and it seems to work.  I'm running postgresql 13.11 on debian.

Comment: No idea about the auto increment, I didn't know that was a thing.

Comment: I'm creating the db from scratch so maybe try the script on another test db and see if it works.  In case there is some cruft in the existing db making it not work.

Comment: Ok I will investigate more. Thanks a lot for the help so far.
I will mark your answer as accepted. I will add an update as soon as I figure out why this happening in my setup.